# Почему два одинаковые алгоритмы дают разный результат?

Tags: java, python, алгоритм

---

Уже много раз сталкиваюсь с одной проблемой. Есть два алгоритма на Java и Python. Алгоритм на Java успешно прошел свое [тестирование](https://algotester.com/en/ArchiveProblem/Display/20110), но алгоритм на Python (точно такой же, как и на Java) видает ошибку (Wrong answer 1).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Алгоритм на Java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    final static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = scanner.nextInt(), in = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String event = scanner.next();

            if (event.equals("In")) {
                in++;
            } else {
                if (in > 0) {
                    in--;
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Error");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

        if (in > 0)
            System.out.print("Cunning elector");
        else 
            System.out.print("Just a fantasy");
    }
}
```

### Алгоритм на Python

```py
import sys

count = input()
count = int(count)
inside = 0

for _ in range(count):
  event = input()

  if event == "In":
    inside += 1
  else: 
    if inside == 0:
      print("Error")
      sys.exit()
    else:
      inside -= 1

print("Cunning elector" if inside else "Just a fantasy")
```

---

### Вопрос

Возможно я что-то не так понимаю или Algotester дискриминирует Python? Это уже не первая подобная ситуация. Возможно, я не знаю какие-то тонкости алгоритмов на Python?

Comment: `видает ошибку` можете в виде текста приложить ошибку?

Comment: Задание? Формат ввода/вывода? Разница может быть в том, что `Scanner::next` отдаст строку без лишних пробелов, даже если они есть во вводе, да и несколько токенов из одной строки может прочитать, в отличие от `input()`.

Comment: @gil9red Wrong answer 1. На картинке видно

Comment: проверьте версии питона. https://ideone.com/IM4VRI вот тут например тоже ошибку выдаёт. Не факт что на сайте последняя версия.

Comment: Они вовсе не одинаковые...

Comment: @pavel на сайте Python 3 (так пишет)

Comment: Во-первых, они не одинаковые. Во-вторых, версию на Java вы запускали 8 месяцев назад. Задание внезапно могло поменяться, и старый алгоритм может не проходить тесты.

Comment: @insolor я только что опять отправил алгоритм на Java и он успешно прошел проверку

Comment: Возможно `sys.exit()` не является ожидаемым поведением для тестируемого скрипта. Попробуйте избавиться от него.

Comment: @insolor 1. В первом тесте должен быть ответ "Cunning elector", поэтому до sys.exit() не доходит. 2. В другом задание sys.exit() не мешал

Comment: Если сделать `event = input().strip()`, то тесты проходит: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYlPt.png

Comment: @insolor действительно, спасибо. Теперь я буду знать, что scanner::next обрезает лишние пробели)) Если хотите — напишите как ответ, я отмечу

Comment: Не хочу. Это не программная проблема, это проблема конкретно того сайта.